# Size of a queue for BFS in a grid

Tags: algorithm

I want to run a BFS in a square grid of size N*N. There is a single starting node. I can only move up/down/left/right (not in diagonal). ***There may be obstacles in the grid.***

Of course I want to use a queue to store the nodes I have to visit. It will be implemented as circular array of size S (fixed size). What is the minimum size for my array? I don't want it to overflow, even in the worst possible case.

A similar problem would be : given a node in a grid, what is the maximum number of node at  exactly distance K from the starting node (for any 0 < K < 2*N)?

I think it would be hard to find an exact answer to this problem so a good approximation would be enough.

See this example (the rightmost picture) :

[image]

This is not a grid but we could make grid with the same pattern (where the white represents obstacles and the black fractal are the walkable nodes). We can see that we have a lot of nodes at ***EXACTLY***  the same distance from the node in the center (actually this number doubles everytime time a path splits in two). 
So I would like to know how large this number could get, and if there are other configurations that yields to the same situation.

To make it very clear my question is : can this number get LARGER than 2*N where N is the size of the N*N square grid.

Comment: Can you pass by a same node in the grid more the once, until you have to empty your queue? If not, in the worst case, you may run the entire grid, or N^2 positions. Otherwise, what is the restriction, since you may have to stop sometime?

Comment: This is a BFS so every node will be added (and popped) only once. I cannot have N*N positions at the same time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't really get the problem. You have a grid, NxN, and, from a given point, you perform a BFS. What are the child nodes of a determined node in the grid? Their neighbors that haven't been considered siblings? And what would it be to have obstacles? In a grid of 3x3, if you start from the leftmost topmost node in the grid, how does you your search span? Could you give an example?

Comment: When do you stop visiting a node? For example, is it possible to visit nodes 1-2-1-2-1-2 ?

Comment: I am going to post a new example

Comment: Also, don't forget that in a breadth-first search, every cell may occur more than once in your queue, simply because there are multiple paths to it. So an upper bound on the maximum number of cells at a distance K is not sufficient to determine your maximum array size.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you want to know the number of cells at distance K because you want to know the maximum size of your queue?

If so, why not just use a circular buffer based on a list instead (or, alternatively, use an array and reallocate a larger one yourself once the buffer is full)?

This skips your problems altogether, and the list resizing behaviour shouldn't be a problem: most implementations double the size of the underlying array if they run out of space, so you shouldn't get more than O(log n) reallocations anyway.

Comment: Yes this is exactly why I want to compute the size of my array. Except I know I can use linked list, or resizable array. I only ask because I am interested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the maximum distance of a node from the starting node might be > `2*N` because of the existence of obstacles:

```
. . . * . . .
. * . * . * .
. * . * . * .
. * . * . * .
. * . . . * .
. . * * * . .
. . A * B . .
```

If I counted correctly, the distance from A to B is 30, which is quite a lot more than 2*7.

If it were not for obstacles, it would be easy to compute the maximum size of the fringe, which would be a simple diamond of edge `K` (or the part of it which overlaps the grid), and consequently of maximum size `2*N`.

As the above example shows, the obstacles can increase the length of the shortest path between two nodes. Can they increase the maximum possible fringe size? I can't quickly come up with an example where they do, and I suspect that they can't, but I can't think of a quick proof either.

Comment: I am no trying to compute the maximum distance between 2 nodes but the maximum nodes at a certain distance.

Comment: @user1637030, I understood that. But you ask, "what is the maximum number of node at exactly distance K from the starting node (for any 0 < K < 2*N)?" which I understood to mean that you thought 2*N was the maximum distance from the starting node, which (if I understand what you mean by obstacle) is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this number can get larger, and it should be very easy to visualise using the third image
you provided.

Imagine that you start only with the top-left quarter of that figure. This defines N as the
size of that top-left quarter, and E as the number of endpoints all with the same distance to the center cell.

Now imagine that you want to expand your grid to the complete figure. This means that your Nnew is now 2N (i.e. the length has doubled, and so has the width). However, the number of endpoints E is now quadrupled (i.e. Enew = 4N), as can be observed in the figure.

In other words, as N increases, the number of endpoints grows much faster than N, and therefore
the number of endpoints is bound to exceed 2*N for a big enough N.